Fluent Bit as Syslog Server Alternative
We have an application deployed on AWS EKS cluster, which has a requirement of sending the application error messages to a syslog server.
Our default logs shipper is Fluent Bit, deployed as a Daemonset in the AWS EKS cluster.
Going over the official documentation of Fluent Bit,
There is an option for a Syslog input, which allows to collect Syslog messages through a Unix socket server (UDP or TCP) or over the network using TCP or UDP.
But looking over the example in official documentation:
[SERVICE]
    Flush               1
    Log_Level           info
    Parsers_File        parsers.conf

[INPUT]
    Name                syslog
    Path                /tmp/in_syslog
    Buffer_Chunk_Size   32000
    Buffer_Max_Size     64000
    Receive_Buffer_Size 512000

[OUTPUT]
    Name   stdout
    Match  *

It seems that Fluent Bit,
Can't receive any Syslog traps (like for example: Kiwi Server), but only performs a tail action, on the Syslog log file (in the example: /tmp/in_syslog).
Did I correctly understand the official documentation?

I don't believe "syslog traps" are a thing; could you be thinking of SNMP traps?  SNMP is not part of syslog.

It seems you can use Syslog input plugin to configure Fluent Bit to collect Syslog messages through a Unix socket or TCP/UDP socket. Please scroll down in the documentation to see other examples than the file parsing one.
Look at these options:
Parser   syslog-rfc3164
Listen   0.0.0.0
Port     5140


Thank,
In case you are refereeing to the section of "Rsyslog to Fluent Bit: Network mode over TCP", does Fluent Bit will pull the Syslog traps, or will listen to the Syslog traps?

What do you mean by syslog traps? I recall about SNMP traps, but they are a different thing.

Sorry for the wrong terminology, as in the scope of Syslog, it should be Syslog Messages, and if I'm not mistaken the Syslog protocol isn't supporting pulling.

Fluent Bit will listen for syslog messages from a syslog that will connect to it.  This means that you need to configure syslog to connect to Fluent Bit and  also configure Fluent Bit to start a  port in listening mode.

Traditionally, syslogd is collecting log messages from various sources and send them to files or remote syslog servers. It doesn't store the messages into a DB, so you can't poll it.
